# How to compare date value only in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get the records from database where `StartTime` field should be today's date.

```
service.GetAll().Where(o => o.StartTime. == DateTime.Today.Date).Select(o => new SelectableItem(o.Id, o.TestPurpose, v == o.Id))
```

The date in database is of this format.

```
2016-07-01 07:00:00.000
```

How do I compare this format with today's date, I need to compare only date and not the time.

Comment: what is preventing you to use `o.StartTime.Date == DateTime.Today`?

Comment: so is this `o.StartTime.`

Comment: Also `.Date` in `DateTime.Today.Date` is redundant.

Comment: Btw, if your question is how to do that in EF, you should update the tag and question appropriately, because LINQ is too broad.

Comment: @IvanStoev The question specifically refers to the database, so we know it's not an `IEnumerable`, but yes, he should be specific about which query provider he's using.

Comment: Also, on top of providing the... provider.... Just want to be sure that the type you getting from the database is an actual date type.  I've seen terrible database design where it was built using "strings" as the dates... and it infuriates me to no end :)  If that's the case you should cast to the correct type first.

Comment: Yes I need to do this in EF. Also, the date field in database is of type DateTime.

Comment: StartTime is the field name in database.

Answer (score 2):

You can use approach specified by @Renan Araujo. 
Or another way is, define two dates and use

```
.Where(o => o.StartTime >= date1 && o.StartTime < date2)
```

where

```
  date1 = DateTime.Today.Date;            // (lets say today's date=10-13-2016 )
  date2 = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).Date; // (tomorrow's date = 10-14-2016)
```

Comment: @Ian Mercer: Thank you for fixing typos and presenting it in cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

Use [EntityFunctions.TruncateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove the time portion:

```
service.GetAll()
.Where(o => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(o.StartTime) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Today.Date))
.Select(o => new SelectableItem(o.Id, o.TestPurpose, v == o.Id))
```

Comment: SystemNotSupported exception is thrown on using EnityFunctions.TruncateTIme